# An error occurred while calculating code metrics for target file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, code-metrics, cyclomatic-complexity

When i do calculate code metrics to my project, i am getting this error below. How can i solve it?

```
Project: AA.Tests.Repository
Configuration: Debug
Scope: None
Assembly: G:\WS\selin\src\Binaries\Win32\bin\AA.Tests.Repository.dll
Maintainability Index: 
Cyclomatic Complexity: 
Depth of Inheritance: 
Class Coupling: 
Lines of Code: 
Message: An error occurred while calculating code metrics for target file 'G:\WS\selin\src\Binaries\Win32\bin\AA.Tests.Repository.dll' in project AA.Tests.Repository. The following error was encountered while reading module 'AA.Tests.Repository': Assembly reference cannot be resolved: AA.BB.Base, Version=1000.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
```